# How can I increase the knockback of a slime in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using command blocks to make a custom slime, I've tried using the command:  `/summon slime ~ ~ ~ {Size:3b,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.attack_knockback", Base:8.0,}]}`

but it doesn't work. Replacing "slime" with "zombie" does work however. I've tried giving the slime a knockback sword, but they can't make use of items. Is there any way to increase their knockback?

Answer (score 1):

I think this changed in the 1.16 update, when I have worked with this command, I looked it up, and it seems like this attribute now only affects iron golems, Hoglins, and zoglins